# Asynchronous Multiton pattern in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, multiton

I want to cache performance intensive object generation using the Multiton pattern in JavaScript with an asynchronous function. I provide an example and would like to know if I implemented that correctly, i.e. whether that is enough to guarantee that an object with the same name will never be generated twice, no matter the asynchronous order of execution.

```js
const things = new Map();

// in real life, fetch from network or other asynchronous, slow operation
async function slowFunc() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(100));
}

class Thing {
    constructor(n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    static async get(name) {
        let thing = things.get(name);
        if (thing) {
            console.log("Reusing existing", name, "with n=", (await thing).n);
            return thing;
        }
        const promise = slowFunc().then(n => {
            thing = new Thing(n);
            console.log("Creating new", name, "with n=", n);
            return thing;
        }, );
        things.set(name, promise);
        return promise;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="Thing.get('a');">Make an A</button>
  <button onclick="Thing.get('b');">Make a B</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems right. only strange thing is that you have "the creator fn/factory method" as a static function on the very class you want to keep unique instances of

Comment: @japrescott: I did it like this in Java, what is the usual location to put the factory method in JavaScript?

Comment: its not wrong, its just a bit strange :) I normally have a separate Factory class/method which is the only exported method (the class isn't exported thus preventing accidental misusage).

Comment: @japrescott: That makes total sense as JavaScript doesn't have private constructors, thanks!